# Format of messages for iOS push notifications

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Im sending out push notifications successfully, but some characters are not rendering correctly.

For example im sending the word

> Valentine's

but it renders differently in the notification message, it looks like this

> Valentineu2019s

Im using PHP to send out the push notifications, whats the best way to ensure the messages come out cleanly?

Comment: Perhaps show a code example of how you are getting the string, compiling it and sending it to Apple's Notification servers? (It looks like a unicode character encoding issue though)

Comment: In JSON the string would be "Valentine\u2019s", which JSON parsers — including Apple's — would read as 'Valentine's' (with the 'right single quotation mark' per the unicode standard). Is it possible the backslash is being stripped somewhere before the packet goes off to Apple?

Comment: I think you are sending the word Valentine’s, not Valentine's (notice the difference between right single quotation and apostrophe, the former is usually bent on most fonts and has a larger width)